# Oncellclick does not change place in ADOTable. (delphi)

Tags: delphi

I am using the on cell click procedure for a DBGrid to open another form where it shows info about the user you have clicked on  but when I do so it does not change the place in the ADOTable, which it previously did, but instead it just stays in the same place and displays info about yourself and not the user you have clicked on.

I hope I have explained the problem well. If not I will try to explain it better.

Thanks in advance.

```
    procedure TfrmStudentViewer.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       Adoforteachers.active:=false;
       if flagteacher=true then
         Begin
         adoforteachers.sql[2]:='Where (((TBLUsers.Level)=1)) OR  (((TBLUsers.Level)=2))';
         adoforteachers.Active:=true
    End;
```

and onclick is just

```
   procedure TfrmStudentViewer.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
   begin
      frmViewUser.showmodal
   end;
```

Comment: OT: If you were using [`master detail relationship`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships), you wouldn't need to handle the event nor ask this question ;-) Besides, I don't get much from your description. I see, that your dataset cursor is frozen for some reason, but without knowing what you're doing e.g. in that `OnCellClick` event it's impossible to help.

Comment: I might try the master detail relationship. But with existing way I am doing it it only seems to work if I don't use an ADOQuerey which is a bit weired. In essence I have a DBGrid showing Users but want to filter them depending on the type of user. Clicking on the user give you more info about the user in a different form. BTW this is for a first year A-Level Project so still a bit of a noob at Delphi :-P Thanks

Comment: You might get more help if you edit your question to include the source code of your form that has your DBGrid on it, if it's not to long.  There could be all sorts of things wrong and without more it's impossible to say.

Comment: Are you closing and reopening the detail form after you click on a cell: your code is in OnShow event of the form.

Comment: I am not opening and closing the detail form. The code I have put on the thread is the code on the form before (the one with the DBGrid) and I need the code in the on show section.